# The physical meaning of electromagnetic waves

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, displacement, leptons

What, fundamentally, is an electromagnetic wave? As far as I know, all wave phenomena are derivations of an oscillating processes, e.g. particles vibrating in a medium. I can't imagine a wave process which couldn't be explained as moving particles: sound wave - movement of gas molecules, waves on the water - movement of water molecules, earthquake - movement of ground particles (and finally molecules), even phonons - vibrational motion of crystal lattice.  Phonons are virtual but the atoms arranged in lattice are real.

I tend to think that the reason has to do with the restless nature of the photons along with the uncertainty principle - the impossibility to localize a primary chunk of matter (with momentum) - when we catch the wave (stop the process) the frequency is gone. But again, it looks like it is a particle and we just can't observe it with our methods.

So, what is an electromagnetic wave? How can it move vibrating across the vacuum? How can we physically interpret phenomenon of electromagnetic waves?

***Update***

The concept of *field* is itself very complex phenomenon to understand its physical meaning by our "everyday" mind. The field looks like a math tool to describe and predict nature events. But its physical representation is unclear. I can't think of light as some 3-D helix shaped pulsing of continuous substance :) The world is quantized and it's obvious that the `sine`-shape like objects cannot be elementary in reality.

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74276/24774, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15762/24774, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30402/24774

Comment: It *really* is a traveling oscillation of the electromagnetic field.

Comment: The thinking that a wave must have a medium is what led 19th century physicist like Maxwell to obsess over complex constructions of an "aether" filling all space. None of these theories really worked and it was Einstein who finally demolished them all with relativity. The field viewpoint is really fundamental and the particles are a derived concept (in the present understanding). For example, we now understand electrons as excitations of an electron field (this conveniently explains why all electrons are identical). So the medium is the field itself and that all that's needed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether

Comment: Why do you think a field is a purely mathematical tool, and that a point particle is not?

Comment: Yes, `particle` (without surface) itself a mind-blowing concept to acquire, but we can say: _stop thinking - it is elementary and primary thing_, but about `field` which is more complex and composed of virtual particles, it is hard to say `stop`. I didn't say that the `fields` are pure mathematical abstractions (but some of them are).

Comment: I have asked this question many times. No one can ever answer it without incorporating photons.There is no physical description of a wave or a field without a flux of photons. The usual answer is an electromagnetic wave is a field or a field is a wave. Vice a versa back-and-forth that's all you ever get. Electromagnetic wave or field can Only be described with many coherent photons. Rook, I am sure once again that no one will come up with a physical description to answer your question. It can't be done without photons.

Comment: Is “how do I understand fields?” a **new question**?

Comment: Why were [tag:displacement] and [tag:leptons] tags added?

Answer (score 1):

An EMR is a term used to explain the effects "light" has on the electric and the magnetic field. We don't know what light looks like so the only way we can relate it to the physical world is by observing the effects it has on the surroundings. Instead of oscillating particles, it has oscillating electric and magnetic vectors which, again, can't be seen but they can be detected. A field can be imagined as a plane which can have excitations. These excitations mean different things in different fields, for example, in the electron field, excitations represent the chances of an electron being present at that particular place.

Answer (score 0):

Let us start from the beginning, what does physical mean and what does "mean" mean:

> The physical meaning of electromagnetic waves

The language of physics we learn not only at school but by everyday experience, is a language developed to describe the behavior of nature for dimensions larger than 10^-9 cm  , and times larger than 10^-9 seconds; in the present day physics language, dimensions large enough that the   [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle (HUP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) is automatically fulfilled. There is also a mathematical description for students of physics.

So  we have given a " mathematial meaning" to a sea wave , by modelling its *motion in transfer of energy with sinusoidal functions* which are solutions of differential equations.

Then we have instruments which discover *physically* that at the small dimensions of the  HUP there exists a substructure of atoms and molecules. The enlightenment coming from this experimental observation is what powers the "physical" in the title question. It considers "physical" something that can have an experimental under layer which layer can be modeled mathematically again.

As a highschool teacher I had used to say: "problem number one has been reduced to problem number two". I.e., "what is the physical meaning of atoms and molecules" . Again an underlying level was revealed by experimental observations, the quantum mechanical models of atoms and molecules, and again the problem of what is "physical" has been pushed a layer below.

From the above, we can see that the term "physical meaning" is defined by the existence of an experimentally measurable under-layer that explains the behavior under study, pushing the "unknown" a layer below. We are making great efforts with our colliders etc to find lower and lower layers, if they exist. *At present* we are stopped with the [standard model of physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) which has pushed the under-layer to the posited existence of the particles in the table, the elementary particles, which mathematically are modeled as point and are the building blocks up to all layers I have been discussing above.

Notice the photon in this table. It is the building block of the electromagnetic wave, so it is the under-layer of the electromagnetic wave. That is the physical meaning of the electromagnetic wave, that it emerges, its mathematical models, from a confluence of photons. This needs quantum field theory to be understood, but it is just mathematics, as our experiments have not reached an under-layer which will be modeled mathematically so that the photon can be considered a measured confluence of the under-layer, the way the molecules are an under-layer for the water wave.

> So, what is an electromagnetic wave?

An over-layer emerging from the confluence of photons.

> How can it move vibrating across the vacuum? How can we physically interpret phenomenon of electromagnetic waves?

It is riding on an enormous number of photons .  The mathematical description of this [can be seen here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html).

We are stuck with the mathematical meaning because photons themselves are the bottom layer that can be measured in our experiments. That means we are stuck with quantum mechanical mathematical models describing the photons, which correctly gives the E and B fields of the classical wave and their energy transport in space. We have not reached experimentally the point of seeing whether there exists an under-layer to this or not, i.e. whether we have reached the end of the line with the standard model and its extensions as far as describing nature and giving meaning to "physical".

Comment: The underlayer is the photons. So close to the right idea why not continue with that? Photons as particles can derive any of the phenomenon. We can also detect them. There is so much science supporting photons why even incorporate the wave other than a wave of coherent photons?

Comment: @BillAlsept we can detect them , but cannot "explain" them, the way we explain the water waves by the motion of molecules and the molecules by the existence of electrons an nucleons, and the nucleons by the existence of quarks. The physics explanation that he is seeking would come from an underlayer where the mathematical hypotesis will be pushed.

Comment: this is because we cannot measure the complex functions with which we mathematically model photons, or their phases and E and B fields which are there in the complex mathematical form. If we could, we would have found an experimental underlayer .

Comment: why not try? I have offered a hypothetical solution that works. It doesn't involve approximations or uncertainties and it can derive any light phenomena.

Comment: I think we can measure them. You can see and measure them in a single edge or straight edge fringe pattern. All you need to do is go with the simple idea of an oscillating photon. This way has far less to consider than the other wave solutions.

Comment: @BillAlsept  the fringes measure the classical em parameters. A single photon is random when it scatters,

Comment: Yes it is very important that the photons are random as I explained in my paper.

Comment: @BillAlsept  You are just illustrating the mathematical wavefunction of the photon, how it builds the wave. the link of motl does the same with field theory. You are not measuring the underlayer of a single photon, you are just verifying the mathematics. The way somebody would measure interference with water waves by one molecule at a time, but that says nothing about the underlying  structure of the molecules.

Comment: But it does because along with deriving the solution I also offer a model that works. The wave does not offer any physical solution to how it could even happen. It's not accountable for itself. What is wrong with an actual particle that can oscillate as it travels along?

Comment: @BillAlsept  That is what the photon is doing in QFT,  but it is still not the underlevel, which would give the "physical" meaning . You are just restating the standard model hypothesis in your particular model ( I do not know whether it is consistent with all the rest of the SM). Nohing wrong, but it does not fall into the "physical " definition I am discussing above.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to discuss. I know we're not supposed to go into full discussions here or hijack someone else's question. I did not mean to do that but I would love to discuss these types of things in more detail sometime. Thanks